# How to not print a line (rather than printing 0) if it doesn't satisfy if statement - Python

Tags: python, if-statement

I want to print out the line count and hashtag count only if the line starts with "RT" AND has at least 1 hashtag in it. 
At the moment my code will print the line if it starts with "RT" but will give a 0 for the hashtag count is 0. However I don't want it to print the line at all.
i.e. there should be no lines of code that print out as "49 : 0"

PLEASE HELP - feel like I'm nearly there but need to add some more code into the second for loop.

```
hashtag_count = 0
line_count = 0

for line in open("tweets.txt"):
    line_split = line.split()
    hashtag_count = 0
    if line.startswith("RT "):
        for word in line_split:
            if "#" in word:
                hashtag_count += 1
        print(str(line_count) + " : " + str(hashtag_count))
    line_count += 1
```

Answer (score 0):

You have reset value of `hashtag_count` in loop, remove that statement

```
hashtag_count = 0
line_count = 0
for line in open("tweets.txt"):
  line_strip = line.strip()
  line_split = line_strip.split()
  hashtag_count = 0 #Remove this line  <----------------------------
  if line_strip.startswith("RT "):
    for word in line_split
      if word.startswith("#"):
        hashtag_count += 1
    print(str(line_count) + " : " + str(hashtag_count))
  line_count += 1
```

After removal it will return number of `hashtag_count` correctly.

Answer (score 0):

```
if hashtag_count:
    print(str(line_count) + " : " + str(hashtag_count))
```

P.S.

> RT

Russia Today? :-O

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I missed something but why you're iterating over words?
If you just need to print only line number with # count for this lines starting with 'RT', try the following:

```
with open("tweets.txt") as f:
    for line_number, line in enumerate(f, 1):
        if line.startswith('RT'):
            hash_count = line.count('#')
            print("{} : {}".format(line_number, hash_count))
```